# Sending system command with arguments in R

Tags: r, bash, ess

I am trying to write a function in R that would allow me to automatically view a data frame using `Libreoffice`. The idea is that when I want to have a look at the data, the function will write a temporary csv file and open it with R. Here's the code that I have:

```
view <- function(data) {
    FILE = "/home/spreadSheetView/temp.csv"
    write.csv(data, file = FILE, row.names = F)
    system(command = "export $(dbus-launch); \
                      export NSS_USE_SHARED_DB=ENABLED; \
                      libreoffice --calc /home/spreadSheetView/temp.csv")
}
```

And the code works. However, instead of using the absolute directory to the file when opening it in `Libreoffice`, I want to use something like `$FILE` or `${FILE}`, and the last line of code will look like:

```
libreoffice --calc $FILE")
```

Sadly the program cannot find the file this way. Could you suggest if there are ways to use this methodology? Thanks!

Comment: Moved the self-answer out of the question into a separate, Community-Wiki answer. See [Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question) on [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
command = paste(
      "export $(dbus-launch); \
       export NSS_USE_SHARED_DB=ENABLED; \
       libreoffice --calc",
     FILE )
system(command)
```

Comment: There's no protection against shell injection attacks via the filename this way, is there?

Comment: At least use [`shQuote`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/shQuote.html)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - good point.  I had assumed that the filename is generated by OP themself, so unlikley to be vulnerable to hostile attacks.  But if there is a risk of external actors injecting code into FILE, then you are correct your method is better.

Answer (score 1):

This Community Wiki answer is taken from a self-answer previously present in the question:

---

> Code based on @CharlesDuffy's answer with some revisions, as I cannot make `/bin/sh` work with `export`.
>
> ```
> view <- function(data) {
>     FILE = "/home/spreadSheetView/temp.csv"
>     write.csv(data, file = FILE, row.names = F)
>     system2(command = "export",
>         args = c("$(dbus-launch) NSS_USE_SHARED_DB=ENABLED; ",
>                  "libreoffice --calc \"$1\" ",
>                   FILE))
> }
> ```

Comment: This shouldn't work -- that it does implies that `system2()`'s behavior isn't as equivalent to a direct `execve()` call as its documentation claims.

Comment: I tested this function again and it works fine for me. I do not see all the ENV variables being printed out, and there's no error regarding `dbus-lauch`.

Comment: `export` isn't an external command; it's purely a shell builtin. Something that does a proper `execve()` shouldn't be able to *run* it at all. I do believe you that it works, but that it works means there's something very wrong.